# Schedule job to run twice a day beginning at 10 AM

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I am new to scheduled batch apex jobs. I am trying to run a job every day at 10 AM and 10 PM but the logic doesn't seem to be working. Here's what I have so far

> Time currentTime = Datetime.now().time();
>
> Time desiredStartTime = Time.newInstance(10, 0, 0, 0);
>
> Integer minutesFromNow = 0;
>
> minutesFromNow = ((desiredStartTime.hour() * 60) + desiredStartTime.minute()) - ((currentTime.hour() * 60) + currentTime.minute());
>
> if (minutesFromNow <= 0) minutesFromNow = minutesFromNow + 720;

When it tries to run at 10PM it gives me this error - First error: minutesFromNow must be non-negative

Comment: How are you scheduling the job? Are you using [System.schedule](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm)

Comment: Yes.System.scheduleBatch(new classname(), JOB_NAME, minutesFromNow, 10);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the examples listed in [System.schedule](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm), you can schedule your job to run everyday at 10am and 10pm using the following code:

```
GXCalculateGranteeTotals job = new GXCalculateGranteeTotals();
String sch = '0 0 10,22 * * ?';
system.schedule(JOB_NAME, sch, job);
```

Or if you only wanted it on weekdays it would be:

```
'0 0 10,22 * * MON-FRI'
```

Comment: And always remember, it's in the user's time zone, not GMT.

Comment: To run it at 6:30 and 8:30, I used this:
String sch = '0 30 6,8 * * ?';

Comment: Yes that would run it at 6:30am and 8:30am